# link farming or lame questioning?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, spam

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594674/wordpress-question-closed

Spam? or not Spam? stackoverflow is a place google likes, so having a link here is attractive.

Edit to give typing instructions for URL to avoid the link?

Comment: I edit, delete the website and add the following comment:  Please don't ask questions like "How do I do what this website is doing:  SomeSpammyWebsiteIWantToDriveTrafficTo.com?"  It makes you look like a spammer that wants to drive traffic to your spammy website.  If applicable, you can take a screenshot of the website (to demonstrate what you are asking for) instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 1):

Lame questioning.

This is a terrible user, but looking at his other questions, a legit one. I don't think the link is spam.

It will also not improve their page rank because Stack Overflow's outgoing links are `nofollow`ed.

Apart from burning the question with fire because it's off-topic, I don't think any action should be taken.